# How to avoid session hijacking in .net core 6 mvc

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

how could we avoid session hijacking problem in our software which build in asp .net core 6 mvc

expecting .net core 6 mvc sample code

How can we prevent session hijacking in an asp.net core 6 mvc application? The following steps were performed by the testers to hijack the session.

Login as a low-privilege user.
Login as a admin user. (in a separate browser - from the same machine)
Copied the ASP.Net Session ID of the admin user
Replaced the ASP.Net Session ID of the low-prev user with the that of the admin user.
By doing the above steps, the low-prev user was able to access the admin areas of the app.

The application is hosted with SSL (https).
Cookies have been set to Secure and HttpOnly.
Cookies are set to expire on Session_End and Signout.
Still, I am able to reproduce the scenario explained above using Fiddler. Could someone please help on ways to arrest the above issue.

Thanks.

Comment: The thing is if you could get the session id from the cookie, you could get anything include all the cookie or else.  Just avoid session id is useless.

Answer (score 1):

This is like asking how to avoid account hijacking using the privileged user’s password. If someone can read your cookies, you’re pwn’d, but it’s not the web app’s fault. The user and their system need to take care not to let their cookies/session IDs fall into the wrong hands.

Of course you can implement some mitigations:

- Fingerprint the user’s environment (e. g. user agent, IP) and make them reauthenticate when it changes. This might not help if, as in your example, the attacker is on the same machine.
- Shorten the server-side session lifetime so the attacker needs to work quickly. This seems kind of pointless for your scenario as well.
- Always force users to reauthenticate for especially sensitive operations such as editing their account or placing an order.

Here is a simple example that hashes UA and IP and compares this fingerprint to the one stored in the session. If it doesn’t match, the user is redirected to an page where you can prompt for credentials. This assumes you’re using the Session service (`builder.Services.AddSession()`). Upon login you would call `context.Session.SetString("fingerprint", context.Request.GenerateFingerprint())`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace MyApp.Middlewares
{
    public static partial class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static string GenerateFingerprint(this HttpRequest request)
        {
            var data = request.Headers.UserAgent.ToString() + request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
            using var md5 = MD5.Create();
            return Convert.ToHexString(md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)));
        }

        public static bool HasValidFingerprint(this HttpContext context)
            => context.Session.GetString("fingerprint") == context.Request.GenerateFingerprint();
    }

    public class SessionFingerprintMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;

        public SessionFingerprintMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) => this.next = next;

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            //"redirect-after-reauth" is used here as a hack to prevent infinite redirects, clear it when you’re done with it
            if (!context.HasValidFingerprint() && !context.Session.Keys.Contains("redirect-after-reauth"))
            {
                context.Session.SetString("redirect-after-reauth", context.Request.Path);
                context.Response.Redirect("/please-reauthenticate/");
                return;
            }

            await next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

In real life this would probably be way too annoying because the IP would change at the whims of your ISP and the UA changes with every browser update, so you would have to do something more complicated. For example you might store values individually and only trip when more than one change at the same time, or geolocate the IP and chill as long as it’s the same country.

Also if you’re using a reverse proxy, getting the client’s IP may be more involved than the above example.

Comment: can you provide code to fingerprint the user’s environment (use browser fingerprint, etc.)?

Comment: @EmreBener i added a couple of lines, but your approach is going to vary wildly with your requirements